# Close the foreground process when a background process finishes

Tags: linux, bash

For instance, how would I kill tail when wget finishes.

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example.jpg &
tail -f example.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is better - i haven't tested it though:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=example.log
> $LOGFILE # truncate log file so tail begins reading at the beginning
tail -f $LOGFILE &
# launch tail and background it
PID=$!
# record the pid of the last command - in this case tail
wget --output-file=$LOGFILE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example.jpg
kill $PID
#launch wget and when finished kill program (tail) with PID
```

This counts on the fact that tail although in the background will still show it's output on a console. This won't be as easily redirectable though.

Comment: Please avoid a `kill -9`, when a normal `kill` will also do, as it is the equivalent of pulling the power under a process and not letting him time to do any housekeeping on shutdown.

Comment: Just thinking about this some more - namely that it would make better sense to have the kill on it's own line so it runs regardless of the success of wget.